# VIM: Show a 3 character border on left of window

Tags: vim

### Context

I'm using the NERDTree plugin.

The one thing that irks me is the visual vertical border between the NERDTree itself and my code. I find it slightly annoying to read my code. My current setup looks something like:

```
........................#________________________________________________
........................#________________________________________________
........................#________________________________________________
........................#________________________________________________
........................#________________________________________________
........................#________________________________________________
........................#________________________________________________
........................#________________________________________________
........................#________________________________________________
........................#________________________________________________
........................#________________________________________________
........................#________________________________________________
```

where the ... = NERDTree, the *_* = my actual code, and the ### = some vertical grey border.

Now, what I want is something like this:

```
........................#   ________________________________________________
........................#   ________________________________________________
........................#   ________________________________________________
........................#   ________________________________________________
........................#   ________________________________________________
........................#   ________________________________________________
........................#   ________________________________________________
........................#   ________________________________________________
........................#   ________________________________________________
........................#   ________________________________________________
```

The idea is that I somehow inject a 3 character border between the vertical divider of the NERDTre and the left of my actual code.

Now, I can almost achieve this via "set nu" -- except instead of getting spaces, I get a bunch of numbers. I would like something like "set nub", except instead of line numbers, I just get spaces.

### Question:

How do I achieve the above?

Comment: _`I find it slightly annoying to read my code`_ - Great for out of context quoting. _SCNR_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`foldcolumn`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27foldcolumn%27) to create a gutter:

```
:set foldcolumn=3
```

If this adds fold markers to the gutter and you're not using folds at all, then you can set [`foldmethod`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27foldmethod%27) to `manual` so that no folds are created automatically:

```
:set foldmethod=manual
```

Comment: I like the abuse-of-vim-features / creativity of this solution.