# VIM center text to screen, with left and right inactive borders

Tags: user-interface, vim, terminal, ubuntu-14.04, text-editor

I use `vim` to edit text files. My screen is too wide and it's cumbersome to always look near left border of screen when editing. If you open a document in MS Office, the page is "centered" instead of left-aligned, and has non-active area borders on RHS and LHS. How do I get similar behavior from `vim`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are a couple approaches that won't work too well:

First, if you read [VIM: Show a 3 character border on left of window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10778123/2314532) or [MacVim: how do I set a left gutter (margin) for my buffers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7941427/2314532), you might try this:

```
:set foldcolumn=50
```

This **won't work**, because the maximum value of `foldcolumn` is limited to 12.

Second, if you read [How to create a border between the line numbers and text in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12792649/2314532), you might try using `numberwidth` instead of `foldcolumn`:

```
:set numberwidth=50
```

But this **won't work** either, because the maximum value of `numberwidth` is limited to 10.

The best approach that **will work**, as far as I've been able to find, is https://superuser.com/q/537584/376367. See that question's answer for more details, but the summary is: create two vertical splits, and edit your file in the middle. If the vertical divider lines and tildes bother you, you could hide them with:

```
:highlight VertSplit guifg=bg guibg=bg
:highlight NonText   guifg=bg
```

**Caution:** if you use `listchars`, they also use `NonText` highlighting and will also be hidden by this trick.

Answer (score 9):

A plugin which centers the text and removes distractions for you is [Goyo](https://github.com/junegunn/goyo.vim), especially useful in combination with [Limelight](https://github.com/junegunn/limelight.vim).

[image: Goyo in action]